# Better to use declarations or self to modify variables

Tags: javascript

This is probably a stupid question, but im wondering which is better practice for JS

```
    var expireDefault = new Date();
    expireDefault.setYear(expireDefault.getFullYear() + 1);
```

This is how i am getting next years date at run time. 
I have been told however to use a seperate Date() decleration.

```
    var today = new Date();
    var expireDefault = new Date();
    expireDefault.setYear(today.getFullYear() + 1);
```

Is this necsecary ? Or does it even matter ?

In my opinion from this example i dont circular reference.
But the principles remain the same.

Comment: If you need a reference to the original `today` value later in your code, you have to use the second example. It depends on how you're actually using this code.

Comment: That makes sense. no point in re-declaring the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are equivalent.

The second one is just uselessly verbose and heavy. Don't use it : it hides the simplicity of what is done.

Comment: And it wastes time and memory creating a new object just to get information that the first one already has.

Comment: That's as simple and concise as it gets! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The second one is only necessary if you want to use later today's date. If not, you are unnecessarily using memory to store a `Date` object and so, first option is better.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the first approach, it reads better, but that's just an oppinion. Take a look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), which is an amazing lib dealing with dates.

Comment: i actually really like that momentjs